# Copying a working Linux instead of installing a new one

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, cp, dd

It is possible to move an installed Linux from one drive to another or from one disk to another by two methods:

1. `dd` command which copies sector by sector including boot sector
2. `cp` command, and then installing/updating `grub`

These are very handy and easy methods, but I have no seen any instruction for using these methods for installing a new Linux on a new machine. Is there any disadvantage for this?

For example, we can boot from a Live CD, and copy the files of a minimal installed Linux (without grub); then installing grub through `chroot`. In other words, we can have a minimal linux on a USB drive, and install it on any machine (by boot from it, copy itself, chroot, etc).

The only things that should be altered (to my knowledge) is `grub` and `fstab` from on machine to another. Is there any disadvantage or drawback?

NOTE: I know that Live CD installers somehow do a similar task, but I am curious if simple copying can cause problem on a new machine?

Comment: Live CDs and USB-drive distributions are very different beasts. A live CD is designed to run from read-only media and often uses tricks like file system overlays and such, which is not needed when running from read/write media such as a USB flash drive. The former has complexity which simply is not needed for an installed distribution. USB flash drive installations are much closer to a plain Linux distribution installation.

Comment: Right. Live CD/USB images that offer an "install to hard drive" mode generally run an *actual* installation process from their parent distros rather than doing a 1:1 copy of the active system.

Comment: For variations, see other questions tagged [tag:cloning].

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

Mount the two disks to i.e `/old` and `/new`, and issue a rsync between them, (`AS ROOT`)

`rsync -av --delete /old /new`

Afterwards chroot into /new and restore grub configuration. (and fstab)

Comment: Thanks for your supportive reply. I want to know if there is a possible for copying an installed linux to another machine (with different specification). Or is it safe to copy a working linux between different machines (not disks).

Comment: @All I don't get it, over network? If it's local, I already gave you a workable way

Comment: @All it's all safe, I've done this multiple time, just remember to fix the fstab and other stuff you might think of

Comment: @warl0ck It's still safe even if it's not local; `rsync` can do its magic over a network just as easily, after all.